# visualstudio 2010 web application Build Mode for 32bit and 64bit separately

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, iis-7

In visualstudio 2010 web application where can I change configuration for BuildMode Any CPU to 32 bit mode or 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Build => Configuration Manager" you can change the platform for your project, for either Debug or Release mode.